# how to draw connecting lines between buttons in android

Tags: android, button, drawing, lines

I just started programming in android and I want to draw a line that connects buttons that I click on. I have a gridLayout with a lot of buttons that are defined in the main XML file. I would like to have a straight line drawn from the center of the first clicked button to the next button I push, and so on (sometimes ending at the first button I clicked, so it makes some shape). I have done a lot of research on canvases, animations but can't figure out where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks.

RG

P.S. I would eventually like to animate the connecting lines, but first things first.

Comment: Did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do the drawing would be to override the `draw`-method of your `GridLayout`. Notably not the `onDraw` method, since that one gets called *before* your child views are drawn and would thus put your lines into the background. Remember to call the super method *before* doing your drawing.

After the first layout pass (i.e. after `onLayout` has been called at least once) the positions of your buttons should be initialized. You can get their relative positions to their parent by calling `getLeft`, `getTop` etc. on them. You can use that to calculate their center coordinates.

You will have to tell your `GridLayout` somehow on which buttons to draw the lines. Easiest way would probably be to give each button an `OnClickListener`, and tell their parent (`getParent`) that it was clicked and should thus start drawing lines accordingly, for example by building up a set of line objects with the coordinates of the clicked buttons. To force a redraw of the `GridLayout` after each click you can call `invalidate` on it.

Comment: he specifically wrote that you should not override the onDraw method , but the draw method (though i'm not sure why since when you draw the content , the view should already know its size and its children's sizes) : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#draw(android.graphics.Canvas)

Comment: The draw method gets called repeatedly every time anything changes about the GridLayout that requires it to be redrawn (mostly after invalidate was called). The OnClickListener just "registers" a button with the GridLayout, and the draw method just draws all lines of all previously registered buttons everytime it is called. Doesn't matter if there are no lines to draw the first time draw is called. Just call invalidate after a button was clicked and draw will be called again.

Comment: There a 3 draw methods in each ViewGroup, "draw", "onDraw" and "dispatchDraw". "dispatchDraw" takes care of drawing the child views and is called *after* "onDraw" is called. Both are called within the "draw" method of the ViewGroup class. So if you draw the lines within "onDraw", they will be overdrawn by a later call to "dispatchDraw". Best way to understand this really is to look at the source code of ViewGroup. Possible that I mixed it up, but I think thats how it works. Just give it a try.

Comment: A very informative response, again my thanks. A final question: All of this can be done in the activity class, and does not need to be done in a separate class that extends View, correct?

Comment: No, you do have to subclass GridLayout for that. You can include your class in a layout file by using the fully qualified class name (i.e. <com.example.android.MyGridLayout />)

Comment: As opposed to a nested private class? Or just include the full class name in the main XML layout file?

Comment: Has to be a public static or public top level class so that it can be inflated. Just put it where your GridLayout was previously.

Comment: @Timo Ohr: Any link to the practical implementation to this approach?